# How to send correctly a table by email in python?

Tags: python, datatables

i trying to send a ASCII table by email but when i received i got a unexpected format

the format that shows in my python script is

```
from tabulate import tabulate
message_launch = ['value','value2','value3','value4','value5','value6']
headers = ['data_a','data_b','data_c','data_d','date_e','data_f']
**t = tabulate(message_launch, headers=message_headers, missingval='?', stralign='center', tablefmt='grid').encode('utf-8')**

(Pdb) type(t)
<type 'str'>
```

+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+
|  data_a    |  data_b  |  data_c    |   data_d |   data_e       |   data_f     |
+============+==========+============+==========+================+==============+
|    value1  |   value2 |   value3   |   value4 | value5         |  value6     |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+-+

and the table that i got from my email is very disordered
how can i receive in the correct the way the table by email ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most email clients support html rendering. I think that would be the easiest way.

Pass `'html'` to `tablefmt`:

`t = tabulate(message_launch, headers=message_headers, missingval='?', stralign='center', tablefmt='html').encode('utf-8')`

Then send `t` as html with whatever email library you are using.

Comment: @HumbertoPerez What doesn't work? What have you tried? How it doesn't work? You can update the original question with these details.

Comment: i mean that i am still got the disordered message, but i find that is only with outlook, because with thunderbird looks good