# How to keep string formatting when sending an email.message via smtplib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

I am using Python34 to send messages via email. A part of the message is tabular. The column aligment gets all messed up in the email. Here is an illustration of how I am adding tables to the message:

```
import email.message
import smtplib


rows = [['A','EEEEE','A'],
['BB','DDDD','BB'],
['CCC','CCC','CCC'],
['DDDD','BB','DDDD'],
['EEEEE','A','EEEEE']]

msg_text = ""
for row in rows:
    msg_text += "{:<8}{:<8}{:<8}\n".format(row[0], row[1], row[2])

msg = email.message.Message()
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
msg['From'] = 'sender@from'
msg['To'] = 'receiver@to'
msg.add_header('Content-Type','text/plain')
msg.set_payload(msg_text)

smtp_connection = smtplib.SMTP('HHHHUB02', 25, timeout=120)
smtp_connection.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

print(msg.as_string())
```

It looks like this on my terminal:
[terminal print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA6Nd.png)

It looks like this on my email:
[email print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWLae.png)

How to keep string formatting when sending an email.message via smtplib?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send correctly a table by email in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568771/how-to-send-correctly-a-table-by-email-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link. That solution is not really suitable though, as it requires substantial changes. First, it requires the tabular package which is not currently part of our distribution. Second, it requires refactoring our code, as the message is only partly tabular (have updated my question to highlight this fact).

Comment: Perhaps you need to change your content type to html and specify a monospaced font.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood. I am not 100% sure about what your suggestion is. Could you please explain exactly what you suggest I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - how to change email text typeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011992/python-how-to-change-email-text-typeface)

Comment: Thanks @khelwood. I actually needed something a bit more elaborated to compile the various pieces of text and tables in my code into an html message. I've edited my question with the code I ultimately used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(**solution**)
With the code below I was able to combine text and tables in an htlm message that preserved table alignment.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

html_font_style = 'style="font-size: 13px; font-family: calibri"'

message = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
message += '<html>\n'
message += '<body>\n'

text = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA \n"
text += "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB \n"
text_html = "<p {}> {} </p>\n".format(html_font_style, text.replace('\n', '\n<br /> '))

table_html = '<table {}>\n'.format(html_font_style)

table_data = [['A','EEEEE','A'],
['BB','DDDD','BB'],
['CCC','CCC','CCC'],
['DDDD','BB','DDDD'],
['EEEEE','A','EEEEE']]
for data in table_data:
    table_html += '  <tr>\n'
    table_html += '    <td> '
    table_html += ' </td> <td> '.join(data)
    table_html += ' </td>'
    table_html += '  </tr>\n'
table_html += '</table>\n'

message = message + text_html + table_html
message += '</body>\n'
message += '</html>\n'

msg = MIMEText(message, 'html')
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
msg['From'] = 'sender@from'
msg['To'] = 'receiver@to'

smtp_connection = smtplib.SMTP('HHHHUB02', 25, timeout=120)
smtp_connection.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```